# How to select row according to row in range of table 1 date with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to select picture file from `photo_db` where sid is the same as `allotment_db` so I wrote:

```
//allotment_db
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
|   id    |  rm_id  |    date   |  stts   |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
|    1    |     1   |2019-10-01 |    1    |
|    2    |     2   |2019-10-01 |    1    |
|    3    |     3   |2019-10-01 |    1    |
|    4    |     1   |2019-10-02 |    1    |
|    5    |     2   |2019-10-02 |    1    |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to select one row from `photo_db` ...

```
//photo_db
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|    id   |   rm_id   |   file   |    var    |
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|    1    |     1     |  rm1.jpg |     0     |
|    2    |     1     |  rm2.jpg |     0     |
|    3    |     1     |  rm3.jpg |     9     |
|    4    |     2     |  rm4.jpg |     0     |
|    5    |     2     |  rm5.jpg |     9     |
|    6    |     2     |  rm6.jpg |     0     |
|    7    |     3     |  rm7.jpg |     0     |
|    8    |     3     |  rm8.jpg |     0     |
|    9    |     3     |  rm9.jpg |     9     |
|    10   |     1     | rm10.jpg |     0     |
+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Then, I wrote:

```
select * 
  from allotment_db alm 
  left 
  join photo_db pic 
    on pic.id = alm.id
where alm.date between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-02'  
   and alm.stts = 1
   and pic.var = 9
group 
    by alm.rm_id
```

And expect the result would come like this

```
//allotment_db
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|   id    |  rm_id  |    date   |  stts   |  file   |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    1    |     1   |2019-10-01 |    1    | rm3.jpg |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    2    |     2   |2019-10-01 |    1    | rm5.jpg |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    3    |     3   |2019-10-01 |    1    | rm9.jpg |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    4    |     1   |2019-10-02 |    1    | rm3.jpg |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    5    |     2   |2019-10-02 |    1    | rm5.jpg |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

But the actual result return nothing even an error. Please correct me.

Comment: Let me geuss you got a *"SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.alm.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"* error? -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a26b5ekdyBkA12Z6gNDr32/0 as that is not how to should be using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: There's no Sid here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you should be using GROUP BY standard wise, also GROUP BY is not meant to "unduplicate" like that..

I assume you get a error when running your query?

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'alm.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

From what it looks like you seams to be wanting these query resultsets to be merged as one resultset.

**Query #1**

```
    SELECT 
       allotment_db.id
     , allotment_db.rm_id
     , allotment_db.date
     , allotment_db.stts /* or (SELECT 1) AS stts -> 1 AS stts   instead */ 
    FROM 
     allotment_db 
    WHERE 
         allotment_db.date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-02'
       AND
         stts = '1'
    ;

| id  | rm_id | date       | stts |
| --- | ----- | ---------- | ---- |
| 1   | 1     | 2019-10-01 | 1    |
| 2   | 2     | 2019-10-01 | 1    |
| 3   | 3     | 2019-10-01 | 1    |
| 4   | 1     | 2019-10-02 | 1    |
| 5   | 2     | 2019-10-02 | 1    |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
    SELECT 
        photo_db.rm_id
      , photo_db.file
    FROM 
     photo_db 
    WHERE 
      photo_db.var = '9'
    ;

| rm_id | file    |
| ----- | ------- |
| 1     | rm3.jpg |
| 2     | rm5.jpg |
| 3     | rm9.jpg |
```

So a option would be ..

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   allotment_db.id
 , allotment_db.rm_id
 , allotment_db.date
 , allotment_db.stts /* or (SELECT 1) AS stts -> 1 AS stts   instead */  
 , photo_db.rm_id
 , photo_db.file
FROM (
  SELECT 
     allotment_db.id
   , allotment_db.rm_id
   , allotment_db.date
   , allotment_db.stts /* or (SELECT 1) AS stts -> 1 AS stts   instead */ 
  FROM 
   allotment_db   
  WHERE 
       allotment_db.date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-02'
     AND
       stts = '1'
  ) AS allotment_db
INNER JOIN (   
  SELECT 
      photo_db.rm_id
    , photo_db.file  
  FROM 
   photo_db 
  WHERE 
    photo_db.var = '9'
  ) AS photo_db
ON
 allotment_db.rm_id = photo_db.rm_id
ORDER BY 
   id ASC
 , allotment_db.rm_id ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id  | rm_id | date       | stts | rm_id | file    |
| --- | ----- | ---------- | ---- | ----- | ------- |
| 1   | 1     | 2019-10-01 | 1    | 1     | rm3.jpg |
| 2   | 2     | 2019-10-01 | 1    | 2     | rm5.jpg |
| 3   | 3     | 2019-10-01 | 1    | 3     | rm9.jpg |
| 4   | 1     | 2019-10-02 | 1    | 1     | rm3.jpg |
| 5   | 2     | 2019-10-02 | 1    | 2     | rm5.jpg |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a26b5ekdyBkA12Z6gNDr32/19)

Comment: Is it able to add another set of sub (select) in the query?